# Using Kotlin Coroutines still no documents

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Kotlin Coroutines but still the Log.d("Products", products.toString()) is returning empty. I tried to check the size of the result in a toast but it is coming as 0. Can anyone please check and tell me why it is happening also the logcat is showing no error.

**SearchItemActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.GridView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

class SearchItemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val products: MutableList<DocumentSnapshot> = mutableListOf()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_item)

        val gridView = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.itemGridView)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try {
                val result = db.collection("product").get().await()
                Toast.makeText(this@SearchItemActivity, "Number of documents in 'product' collection: ${result.size()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                for (document in result) {
                    val uid = document.id
                    val results = db.collection("product").document(uid).collection("products").get().await()
                    products.addAll(results.documents)
                }
                val adapter = ItemUserAdapter(this@SearchItemActivity, layoutInflater, products)
                gridView.adapter = adapter
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@SearchItemActivity, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        Log.d("Products", products.toString())

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val product = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as DocumentSnapshot
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "UID: ${product.id}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**The Firestore structure is like this -**

[image: The collections inside collection]
[image: Inside Projects]

Comment: Isnt your collection named "produts" with an s? edit: oh sorry, read wrong, should be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the following line of code:

```
val result = db.collection("product").get().await()
```

It means that you try to read all documents that exist within the **top-level** collection called `product`. However, as far as I can see in your screenshot, the products exist inside a sub-collection called `products`. If you need to get the products that exist inside the `products` sub-collection of a single document, then you have to create a reference that points to that sub-collection:

```
val result = db.collection("product")
               .document("5s8Qz4T...") //
               .collection("products") //
               .get()
               .await()
```

If you need to get all products within all sub-collections, then you have to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) like this:

```
val result = db.collectionGroup("products") //
               .get()
               .await()
```